# Deduplicate Data Using Having with Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, functions, duplication

I've inherited a DB that was lacking a unique constraint so data was/is duplicated. I'm now trying to remove the duplicate records, then add a constraint to block this going forward.

I have this query:

```
SELECT count(*) as dacount, substr(group_concat(id), (locate(',', group_concat(id))+ 1))
FROM `game`
group by matchid, ordinal
having dacount > 1
order by dacount desc
```

which correctly gives me the `id`s of the rows I need to delete. The problem with this though is that I can't use this as a subquery on the `DELETE` because of the `dacount` with the `having` parameter. Is there another way to do this?

Here was my plan:

```
DELETE FROM game WHERE id IN (SELECT count(*) as dacount, substr(group_concat(id), (locate(',', group_concat(id))+ 1))
FROM `game`
GROUP BY matchid, ordinal
HAVING dacount > 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are restrictions regarding self-joins in MySQL's implementation of `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. The issue is usually solvable by using joins:

```
DELETE g.*
FROM game AS g
  JOIN 
   ( SELECT matchid, ordinal, min(id) AS id 
     FROM game
     GROUP BY matchid, ordinal
     -- HAVING count(*) > 1
   ) AS d
   ON  g.matchid = d.matchid
   AND g.ordinal = d.ordinal
   AND g.id > d.id ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ec4a76b41b8d4d65833d0dce83e0ae2a)**.

---

Another way would be using a `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` construction:

```
DELETE g.*
FROM game AS g
  LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT min(id) AS id 
     FROM game
     GROUP BY matchid, ordinal
   ) AS d
   ON  g.id = d.id 
WHERE d.id IS NULL ;
```

or an `EXISTS` subquery rewritten as a `JOIN`
(delete all games that there exists another game with same `matchid, ordinal` and smaller `id`):

```
DELETE g.*
FROM game AS g
  JOIN 
     game AS d
   ON  g.matchid = d.matchid
   AND g.ordinal = d.ordinal
   AND g.id > d.id
 ;
```